# Error while replacing date in a file using tr command

Tags: pipe, cat, tr

I want to replace date in a file with my date. For this, I am giving below command -

```
tr '2016-05-25' '2016-06-17' < APCSE060.20160525 > TESTFILE
```

alternatively

```
cat APCSE060.20160525 | tr '2016-05-25' '2016-06-17'  > TESTFILE
```

in both commands I got below error -

```
tr: 0653-716 Character range endpoints out of order.
```

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is a command that does a character-by-character translation.  e.g the following command will change the character `e` to an `E`

```
$ echo hello | tr 'e' 'E'
hEllo
```

When you use `2016-05-25` you're telling the `tr` command to switch the characters `2` and `0` and `1` and the *range* `6-0`... which is where it gets confused.

The command you really want to use is sed:

```
$ sed 's/2016-05-25/2016-06-17' < SRCFILE > NEWFILE
```